# python double for loop attrs issue

Tags: python, for-loop, beautifulsoup

So I have following two BeautifulSoup finds and the webpage I am webscraping:

```
r = requests.get("https://www.viperprint.pl/produkt/arkusze-plano/AP01")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
elems = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'tabela_cenowa eprint_product_link add_to_cart_link'})
hehes = soup.find_all('a', {'id': 'dLabel'})
```

What I need to have from this, is a double for loop, which prints lists to separate columns in .csv file.

Here is my problem:

```
>>> for elem, hehe in zip(elems, hehes):
...     nazwa = hehe.get('title')
...     qty = elem.attrs.get('data-qty')
...     print(nazwa, qty)
```

Gives me output bellow. This is wrong, because each element, which is in column 1 (so 'Arkusze PLANO' and all bellow), should be next to each other, and only first number in column 2 ('100'), should be also in one line.

Wrong output:

```
('Arkusze PLANO', '100')

('A1+ (880 x 630 mm)', '250')

('Dwustronnie kolorowe (4+4 CMYK)', '500')

(u'Kreda b\u0142ysk 130g', '1000')

('Bez uszlachetniania (0+0)', '1500')

(None, '2000')
```

Expected output:

```
'Arkusze PLANO';'A1+ 880 x 630 mm';'Dwustronnie kolorowe 4+4 CMYK';u'Kreda b\u0142ysk 130g';'Bez uszlachetniania 0+0';'100'
```

What I was trying to do is to use .attrs function like this:

```
for elem, hehe in zip(elems, hehes):
    nazwa = hehe[0].get('title')
    format = hehe[1].get('title')
    qty = elem.attrs.get('data-qty')
    print(nazwa, format, qty)
```

...but I got following errors and don't know how to proceed further:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 905, in __getitem__
return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 0
```

I am sorry for such long post, but I wanted to provide as many details as possible.

Comment: Seems you just need something like `';'.join("'" + elem + "'" for elem in elems) + ";'" + hehes[0] + "'"`. Using the `csv` module for formatting would be a cleaner way, of course.

Comment: @MichaelButscher can you please tell me where this should be added?

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the desired output you are looking in a list:

```
import requests
import bs4


r = requests.get("https://www.viperprint.pl/produkt/arkusze-plano/AP01")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
elems = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'tabela_cenowa eprint_product_link add_to_cart_link'})
hehes = soup.find_all('a', {'id': 'dLabel'})

results = []

nazwa_list = []
qty_value = None

for elem, hehe in zip(elems, hehes):
    nazwa = hehe.get('title')

    if qty_value == None:
        qty_value = elem.attrs.get('data-qty')

    if nazwa != None:
        nazwa_list.append(nazwa)

nazwa_list.append(qty_value)
results = nazwa_list
```

output:

```
In  [1]: print (results)
Out [1]: ['Arkusze PLANO', 'A1+ (880 x 630 mm)', 'Dwustronnie kolorowe (4+4 CMYK)', 'Kreda błysk 130g', 'Bez uszlachetniania (0+0)', '100']
```

But you state you want to put into a csv. So you could put it into a table, and then work with it that way too if you wanted

```
import requests
import bs4
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get("https://www.viperprint.pl/produkt/arkusze-plano/AP01")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
elems = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'tabela_cenowa eprint_product_link add_to_cart_link'})
hehes = soup.find_all('a', {'id': 'dLabel'})


results = pd.DataFrame()

for elem, hehe in zip(elems, hehes):
    nazwa = hehe.get('title')
    qty = elem.attrs.get('data-qty')
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[nazwa, qty]], columns = ['title', 'qty'])

    results = results.append(temp_df)
```

Comment: Thank you, that indeed gives the output I have asked in my question, but can you please tell me how I can get output "assigned" to the list of qty's ?
So  something like this:

    'Arkusze PLANO';'A1+ 880 x 630 mm';'Dwustronnie kolorowe 4+4 CMYK';u'Kreda b\u0142ysk 130g';'Bez uszlachetniania 0+0';'100'
    'Arkusze PLANO';'A1+ 880 x 630 mm';'Dwustronnie kolorowe 4+4 CMYK';u'Kreda b\u0142ysk 130g';'Bez uszlachetniania 0+0';'250'
    'Arkusze PLANO';'A1+ 880 x 630 mm';'Dwustronnie kolorowe 4+4 CMYK';u'Kreda b\u0142ysk 130g';'Bez uszlachetniania 0+0';'500'

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by assigning the output to the list of qty's.

Answer (score 0):

I have added another loop to have completely desired output.

```
for elem in elems:
    qty = elem.attrs.get('data-qty')
    print(results, qty, pricenum)
```

Thank you all for help!